# Service calls from Intellij are not routed through Fiddler

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fiddler

I'm going crazy here.

I have a local project setup in intellij that makes many different service calls. All I'm trying to do is route those service calls through Fiddler so that I can see headers/bodies for requests/responses easily.

I've read countless posts saying to set the VM options of the intellij configuration to the Fiddler defaults aka

```
-DproxySet=true 
-DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 
-DproxyPort=8888
```

Been there, done that, I've put these arguments is so many different VM option places but nothing seems to work

The Fiddler config settings are all set to default with the only thing I've changed being setting up HTTPS decryption.

The intellij project is Spring Framework running with Maven

I'm fairly new to the Java/Intellij world, but this should be simple. What am I missing, are there any other settings that would step on top of what I'm trying to do?

Edit: Here is the where the code actually makes the service call.

```
public RxWebTarget getWebTarget(int divisionId) {
    ClientHolder clientHolder = this.clients.get(EnumWarehouse.Division.fromId(divisionId));
    RestClientFactory.JaxRSClientPool bagRestClient = clientHolder.pool;
    RxClient rxClient = bagRestClient.getRxClient(clientHolder.poolName);
    return rxClient.target(bagRestClient.getHostName()).path(bagRestClient.getBasePath());
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to pass these variables to the framework you are using for calls instead of pass it as VM paras. Can you update your question with code example where are doing call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lied within the client we were using to actually make the service call.  We were using a JaxRS client.  I setup a simple example using an HttpUrlConnection and things worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That call will only work if divisionId is 71 or 72.  76 and 77 aren't supported yet.